# Reversed variables in concatenated statement, reversing output unexplained

Tags: php, syntax, logic

This is a complete mystery to me.  I have a simple script that outputs the numbers in an array.  Here is what it looks like:

```
<?php
    $numbers = array(1,2,3,4);
    $total = count($numbers);
    $sum = 0;  

    $i = 0;
    foreach($numbers as $count) {
        $i = $i++;

        if ($i < $total) {
            $output = $output . $count;
        }
    }
    echo $output;
?>
```

The numbers come out fine (1,2,3,4) but what baffles me is that when I switch the `$output` variable like so:

```
if ($i < $total) {
    $output = $count . $output;
}
```

The numbers get reversed! (4,3,2,1)  What is the logic behind this?  Is that just the way it is?  I can't believe this to be an arbitrary rule that just exists because it does.

Does anyone have an explanation?

Comment: Like... really? Do you understand what `.` does? Do follow this with pen and paper. Take your time.

Comment: I've never used PHP before, but [a quick Google search](https://www.google.com/?q=php+dot+operator), and a look at the code answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code

```
$output = $output . $count
```

you are concatenating the value in $count to the $output variable creating a string. Therefore at every iteration you are adding to the end of the string the new values

when you reverse the code

```
 $output = $count.$output;
```

You are placing the new values before the actual string so you get the previous string in reverse